# Print each line of a file

Tags: perl

I have a file test.txt that reads as follows:

```
one
two
three
```

Now, I want to print each line of this file as follows:

```
.one (one)
.two (two)
.three (three)
```

I try this in Perl:

```
@ARGV = ("test.txt");
while (<>) {
    print (".$_ \($_\)");
}
```

This doesn't seem to work and this is what I get:

```
.one
 (one
).two
 (two
).three
 (three
)
```

Can some help me figure out what's going wrong?

---

Update : 
Thanks to Aureliano Guedes for the suggestion.
This 1-liner seems to work :
    perl -pe 's/([^\s]+)/.$1 ($1)/'

Comment: @Biffen please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 5):

`$_` will include the newline, e.g. `one\n`, so `print ".$_ \($_\)"` becomes something like `print ".one\n (one\n)`.

Use [`chomp`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) to get rid of them, or use `s/\s+\z//` to remove all trailing whitespace.

```
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  print ".$_ ($_)\n";
}
```

(But add a `\n` to print the newline that you *do* want.)

Comment: it still not working.  This is what I see now, with your code:   
    )(one
    )(two
    )(three

I am still not getting
.one (one)
.two (two)
.three (three)

Comment: @user1758782 You should edit your post to add the current code you're trying and what you're seeing so it can be properly formatted. Anything with multiple lines just doesn't work in comments.

Comment: @user1758782, It's hard to tell from your poorly-communicated description of the output, but it could be that you are trying to read a file with Windows line endings (CR LF) on a unix system (where lines end with LF). Either convert the file (e.g. using `dos2unix`), or remove all trailing white space (`s/\s+\z//`) instead of just line feeds (`chomp`)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the correct answer already given, you can do this in a oneliner:

```
perl -pe 's/(.+)/.$1 ($1)/'
```

Or if you prefer a while loop:

```
while (<>) {
    s/(.+)/.$1 ($1)/;
    print;
}
```

This simply modifies your current line to your desired output and prints it then.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/([^\s]+)/.$1 ($1)/'` seems more secure for his case. Anyway I do prefer regexp for cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

Another Perl one-liner without using regex.

```
 perl -ple ' $_=".$_ ($_)" '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat test.txt
one
two
three

$ perl -ple ' $_=".$_ ($_)" ' test.txt
.one (one)
.two (two)
.three (three)

$
```